# How to populate an ArrayList in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, arraylist

I'm trying to populate an ArrayList in Clojure but I'm getting the following error message

***java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn***

Here is my code:

```
(ns blackhole-v1.core
  (:import [java.util ArrayList])
  (:import [toxi.geom Vec2D])
  (:use [quil.core]))


(def particles (new ArrayList))


(defn add-particle []
;  (particles (.add (new Vec2D (random (width)) (random (height)))))
  (doto (particles)
    (.add (new Vec2D (random (width)) (random (height))))))


(defn setup []
  (smooth)
  (background 0)
  (add-particle))


(defn draw []
  (background 0)
  (dotimes [i (.size particles)]
    (ellipse (.x (.get particles i)) (.y (.get particles i)) 20 20)))


(defsketch blackhole-v1
  :title "black hole v1"
  :setup setup
  :draw draw
  :size [640 480])
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call `(particles)` as a function but its just simple var. Instead of `(particles)` use `particles`

```
(defn add-particle []
;  (particles (.add (new Vec2D (random (width)) (random (height)))))
  (doto particles
    (.add (new Vec2D (random (width)) (random (height))))))
```